# Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver not found, but is in bin\debug folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I am building a asp.net core console app to do some automated input on a website and I decided to use chrome web driver. I stumbled across this error **OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException:The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable**
What I don't understand is the fact that in the debug folder **chromedriver.exe** is clearly seen. I don't see how it cannot be accessed during run-time? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

`var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();`

That is my code for setting it up and this is where the error is thrown at.

Comment: Please do not undelete and edit an old question to a completely new different question. Just create / ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: Thank you @bassfader - I have rolled this question back to the original version.

Comment: @IanKemp I can't create new questions. If I could I would spare the trouble of editing an existing one. I didn't know there was a ban on deleting question. So please take it back to what it was. THnks.

Comment: @steve I have raised a moderator flag, one of them should be able to tell you what's going on.

Comment: @IanKemp alright thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it works but you will have to

1. add the `chromedriver.exe` to your solution by right clicking and select add existing.
2. in the file properties select under "Copy to Output Directory" either "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer"

That's it. It should work.